# How to set time for reminder alert on every month in VB

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently making a billing system and I would like to know how I can set a reminder/ alert date?
I have data that consists of names of the payee and the outstanding amount of the particular payee. Is there a way that I can send a reminder to myself on the outstanding amount after 5 days later once the invoice is generated.

For example, Company ABC purchased products from me on credit. Invoice is created on the day of purchase and reminder would prompt to remind me about the outstanding payment of Company ABC after 5 days.

Can someone help me with the code in VB?
And can it be implemented using VS 2010?

Comment: I have not tried any methods so far because i dont know what are the codes to use and i was not able to find any.. Do you have any suggestions? - @APrough

Answer (score 0):

Lookup System.DateTime (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx )

The VB datatype Date is really a nickname for System.DateTime.

```
Dim TheInvoiceDate As Date = GetTheInvoiceDate()
Dim TheReminderDate As Date = TheInvoiceDate.AddDays(5)
```